# Why is order in firebase is not working, but working fine in console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why is ordering in firebase is not working when the data is rendering, but its work normally in console log

```
export const fetchAPI = (endpoint, dispatchType) => (dispatch) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  dispatch({ type: CHANGE_LOADING, payload: true });
  firebase.database().ref(endpoint).orderByChild('name').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.val() === null) {
      dispatch({ type: CHANGE_LOADING, payload: false });
      reject(false);
    } else {
      snapshot.forEach((snap) => console.log(snap.val()));
      const items = [];
      Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map((snap) => items.push({
        key: snap,
        apiItem: snapshot.val()[snap],
      }));
      dispatch({ type: dispatchType, payload: items });
      dispatch({ type: CHANGE_LOADING, payload: false });
      resolve(items);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run a query on Firebase, it returns three pieces of information for the matching snapshots:

1. Their keys
2. Their values
3. Their relative order

When you call `snapshot.val()` the data is converted into a JSON object, which only has places for keys and values. Keys in a JSON object have no defined order, so the information about the order is lost when you call `snapshot.val()`.

The solution is what you've done at the top of the method: use `snapshot.forEach()` to look over the child nodes in the correct order.